# I want to filter all the value except values in Array

Tags: vba, excel

I want to filter all the values except value in Array i.e. "B400", "A200", "C300".
I tried following code, none of the code is working

```
Dim rDataRange as Range
set rDataRange = Range("A1:P1000")

rDataRange.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>" & Array("B400", "A200", "C300"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

rDataRange.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array("<>B400", "<>A200", "<>C300"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Please help me

Comment: See my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988468/excel-filter-a-column-by-the-first-letters-for-more-than-2-values/51989002#51989002), you can use reverse logic to build an `.AutoFilter` workaround.

Comment: You want to show all values that aren't equal to `B400`, `A200` and `C300`, correct?

Comment: yes. You are correct

Answer (score 0):

Modified for your situation:

```
Option Explicit
Sub AutoFilterWorkaround()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim filterarr As Variant, tofindarr As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'List the parts of the words you need to find here
tofindarr = Array("B400", "A200", "C300")

ReDim filterarr(0 To 0)
j = 0

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If sht.Cells(i, 11).Value <> tofindarr(0) And _
       sht.Cells(i, 11).Value <> tofindarr(1) And _
       sht.Cells(i, 11).Value <> tofindarr(2) Then
        filterarr(j) = sht.Cells(i, 11).Value
        j = j + 1
        ReDim Preserve filterarr(0 To j)
    End If
Next i

'Filter on array
sht.Range("$A$1:$P$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array(filterarr), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to accomplish this then using a filter.

```
Dim lRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    lRow = .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            If .Cells(i, 11).Value = "A200" Or .Cells(i, 11).Value = "B400" Or .Cells(i, 11).Value = "C300" Then
                .Cells(i, 11).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next i

    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

you could still use `AutoFilter()` in a sort of *reverse mode*:

```
    Dim myRng As Range ' helper range variable

    With Range("A1:P1000") ' reference wanted range to filter, header row included
        .AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:=Array("B400", "A200", "C300"), Operator:=xlFilterValues ' filter on "not wanted" values
        If Application.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then ' if any filtered cell other than header row
            Set myRng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' temporarily set 'myRng' to referenced range "not wanted" rows
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove filters and show all rows
            myRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True ' hide referenced range "not wanted" rows, leaving "wanted" rows only visible

            With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' reference referenced range "wanted" rows
                .Select
                ' do what you want with "wanted" rows
            End With

            .EntireRow.Hidden = False ' unhide all referenced range rows
        Else
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove filters
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: @Ravi Kannan, any feedback?