# Excel VBA autofilter for multiple wildcard then change field value and filldown

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofill, autofilter

I have search until I cannot find how to do this and it work properly. What I am trying to do is find a wildcard value that is more than one.  I also would like to fill down column Z.

What is happening is that if I enter more than 1 wildcard it only finds one of them even though the column has many. If there is only 1 returned it inputs Tier 1 then on filldown it defaults back to Tier 2.  What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "*9365*", "*9575*", "*9375*"), _
Operator:=xlOr
With Worksheets("Raw Data").AutoFilter.Range
   Range("Z" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Select
End With
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Tier 1"
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Columns("Z"). _
   SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FillDown
End With
```

I have tried the fix per @dwirony but my values return no data.

```
Sub AutoFilterWorkaround()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim filterarr As Variant, tofindarr As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row

'List the parts of the words you need to find here
 tofindarr = Array("9365", "9375")

ReDim filterarr(0 To 0)
j = 0

For k = 0 To UBound(tofindarr)

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If InStr(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, tofindarr(k)) > 0 Then
        filterarr(j) = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value
        j = j + 1
        ReDim Preserve filterarr(0 To j)
    End If
Next i

Next k

'Filter on array
sht.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=13, 
Criteria1:=Array(filterarr), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

[This is a picture of the result of the filtered list if I manually enter "95"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LACzv.png)
This code did the trick!

```
Sub AutoFilterWorkaround()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim filterarr As Variant, tofindarr As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

'List the parts of the words you need to find here
tofindarr = Array("9365", "9375")

ReDim filterarr(0 To 0)
j = 0

For k = 0 To UBound(tofindarr)

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If InStr(sht.Cells(i, 13).Value, tofindarr(k)) > 0 Then
        filterarr(j) = sht.Cells(i, 13).Value
        j = j + 1
        ReDim Preserve filterarr(0 To j)
    End If
Next i

Next k

'Filter on array
sht.Range("$M$1:$M$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=13, 
Criteria1:=Array(filterarr), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you try defining the range by finding the last visible row and setting all the values to `"Tier 1"` at once?

Comment: You can't use more than 2 criteria with wildcards in `Autofilter` - I wrote a workaround to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988468/excel-filter-a-column-by-the-first-letters-for-more-than-2-values/51989002#51989002). You have to create an array based on your criteria then filter on that.

Comment: @dwirony see my update in my post for more details.  I did try the code from you fix but it returns nothing.  Did I miss something? I have multiple other areas to be able to use this so it could be a HUGE time saver!

Comment: @DanLane So you want to filter on column M, is that right?

Comment: @dwirony yes that is correct.

Comment: And you want to check column A for the value?

Comment: @dwirony the comumn I want to check is M.

Comment: @DanLane Change `filterarr(j) = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value` to `filterarr(j) = sht.Cells(i, 13).Value`

Comment: @dwirony  I got it to work and posted the updated corrected code above.  Thank you!!!