# Use autofilter on more than 2 criteria with logic operators

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I've tried this, but my code returns run-time error 1004. [Use autofilter on more than 2 criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria/54038701)

Does the logic operators have something to do with this?

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("<>*string1*", "<>*string2*", "<>*string3*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: `.AutoFilter` is limited to a max of 2 criteria when using wildcards - I wrote a workaround to this problem on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988468/excel-filter-a-column-by-the-first-letters-for-more-than-2-values/51989002#51989002). You have to build an array with your wildcard criteria then filter on it.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create a Filter column and put an if statement in it? Something like the formulsa below and then just filter on that column

```
=IFERROR(FIND("string1",UPPER(C9)),0)+IFERROR(FIND("string2",UPPER(C9)),0)+IFERROR(FIND("string2",UPPER(C9)),0)
```